# Is there any way of setting the Z-order of controls on a panel to always be on top when a new control is added?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there any way of setting the Z-order of controls on a panel to always be on top when a new control is added? I am creating a card game and I have a Panel with the pictures of the cards in (a new picturebox for each card). When a new picture is added it automatically goes to the back of the panel. Is there any way so it will be always on top? I've tried 'SetChildIndex' but the name of each picturebox will be the same as I'm re-using code. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
private void DealPlayerCard(int cardNum)
{
    string Card = Classes.Deck.GetCurrentCard();
    PictureBox pb = new PictureBox() { Width = 172, Height = 240, SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage };
    pb.ImageLocation = @"Cards\" + Card + ".png";
    int order = 0;

    switch (cardNum)
    {
        case 1:
            pb.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            order = 5;
            break;
        case 2:
            pb.Location = new Point(60, 0);
            order = 4;
            break;
        case 3:
            pb.Location = new Point(120, 0);
            order = 3;
            break;
        case 4:
            pb.Location = new Point(180, 0);
            order = 2;
            break;
        case 5:
            pb.Location = new Point(240, 0);
            order = 1;
            break;
    }

    AddPlayerCard(pb, order);
}

public void AddPlayerCard(PictureBox pb, int order)
{
    pnlPlayer.Controls.Add(pb);
    pnlPlayer.Controls.SetChildIndex(pb, order);
}
```

*EDIT*

Using Sinatr's idea, I have now used the .Tag control property to give the z-order number to each of the controls and then whenever I add a control - simply loop through each control and set the z-order = .Tag property

```
private void DealPlayerCard(int cardNum)
{
    string Card = Classes.Deck.GetCurrentCardPicture();
    PictureBox pb = new PictureBox() { Width = 172, Height = 240, SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage };
    pb.ImageLocation = @"Cards\" + Card + ".png";

    switch (cardNum)
    {
        case 1:
            pb.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            pb.Tag = 5;
            break;
        case 2:
            pb.Location = new Point(60, 0);
            pb.Tag = 4;
            break;
        case 3:
            pb.Location = new Point(120, 0);
            pb.Tag = 3;
            break;
        case 4:
            pb.Location = new Point(180, 0);
            pb.Tag = 2;
            break;
        case 5:
            pb.Location = new Point(240, 0);
            pb.Tag = 1;
            break;
    }

    AddPlayerCard(pb);
    AddToHand("Player");
}

public void AddPlayerCard(PictureBox pb)
{
    pnlPlayer.Controls.Add(pb);
    foreach (Control Control in pnlPlayer.Controls)
    {
        pnlPlayer.Controls.SetChildIndex(Control, Int32.Parse(Control.Tag.ToString()));
    } 
}
```

Comment: Rather than 1 control per card resulting in many cards, consider having a collection of images which you assign to the dealt cards

Comment: An idea: you can monitor for parent children collection (using polling) and force this child to top like you already do. You can use `Tag` to mark such controls.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the name of the control has to do with this and what the purpose of `order` in your code is but to answer your original question... in order to have a newly-added control always on top, you can simply use something like `var someControl = new Control(); somePanel.Controls.Add(someControl); somePanel.Controls.SetChildIndex(someControl, 0);`.

Comment: Because the picurebox is already created, and they all have the same Control.Name, setting the childindex will clash and it doesn't work. I have edited using Sinatr idea and it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `BringToFront()` method, available to every Winform control:

```
controlName.BringToFront();
```

This brings the control `controlName` to the top of the z-order, forcing it to have a z-order of 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`SetChildIndex(System.Windows.Forms.Control child, int newIndex)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_Control_ControlCollection_SetChildIndex_System_Windows_Forms_Control_System_Int32_) to set the z-order.
A control with `newIndex` set to 0, is at the top of the z-order. Controls with higher `newIndex` will be positioned closer to the bottom.